# How can I specify a short form author name in a Bibtex entry?

Tags: bibtex

I'm preparing a paper for a publication, one of my references is an information package put out by the CDC. It has no listed author.

The author tag they suggest using looks like this:

> Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC)

but the AMA-like citation style used by the journal's style file interprets this as:

> [for Disease Control and (CDC), 2010]

That is, it thinks it's a paper by for Disease Control, Centers and (CDC), Prevention.

I tried the shortauthor tag, but it doesn't change the outcome under this template. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to enclose the author field into a second pair of curly braces:

```
author = {{Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC)}},
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth testing the `@manual` or `@misc` template, which don't require an author, rather than twisting the `Author` field of the template you're currently using.

Comment: There's nothing twisted about having `Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC)` in the `author` field. The issue is that the word "and" has a reserved meaning in author and editor fields, leading BibTeX to misinterpret the field as consisting of two separate authors ("Centers for Disease Control" and "Prevention"). Leaving off the `author` field when one exists would be a bad mistake. The only sensible remedy is to encase the entire author field in a second set of curly braces, as is suggested in the other answer.

Comment: @Mico my opinion (and I freely admit it's just that) is that an author is a person - i.e. until we have real AI, a human.

Comment: You may be assigning a more specific meaning to "author" than was intended by the creator of BibTeX. Nothing wrong, really, with considering "corporate authors".

Comment: @Mico that's perfectly possible (bibtex also uses the singular form for plural authors), however if we take `@article` to refer to a paper in a journal, it should have a real author.  Anyway, even if I were to refer to your/lockstep's solution (+1 btw) as a "workaround", it would still work, I merely offer a possible alternative.